# Delete multiple Threads Directly From Database - VBulletin Forum

Tags: php, mysql, forum, vbulletin

Some spammers have crunched my Vbulletin forum with around 12000 posts of links to nefarious websites. It would take hours to delete these posts and threads via the admin tools on my site.

I have noticed all thre threads are stored in the database under the 'thread' table. Can I just delete the rows from this table, or would this cause errors?

Comment: Yes you can do this.  You would just need to understand what commonality the threads have that you can use as criteria for delete.

Comment: Not the person that downvoted, but as is written, this question isn't within scope of Stack Overflow.  Running a sql query against the database directly does have the potential of causing some things to break (depending on if there's anything else that's tied to the posts or not).  Also there's a pretty good chance that you'll accidentally wipe out legitimate posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who looks at this in the future, I figured out a safer way.

If you delete directly from the thread table, other issues may occur. The better option would be to use the Threads > 'Prune' functionality from within VBulletin Admin Control Panel.

Hope this helps.